# Calling images by id (php)

Tags: php, database, image, wamp

I use this code to display image in directory by calling product id + s.jpg

```
<img src="../product_pics/<?php echo $rxd['id'];?>s.jpg">
```

This works well for existing product but won't work if I create new item in database with unique id and matching image in correct directory.

Picture is there, but going to localhost/project1/product_pics/75s.jpg won't show anything except localhost/project1/product_pics/10s.jpg will display image correctly.

I tried to rename picture which works, from 10s.jpg to 75s.jpg (where 10s.jpg display correctly but when renamed to 75s.jpg won't display image)

I am not good with php, I have been told that If I add new column in database with unique ID, and name picture like I showed above, it should work.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I suppose the number is the auto-increment id of the product. When creating the X product, how do you create a Xs.jpg picture in your product_pics folder ?

Comment: I simply put image file into directory and name it Xs.jpg. I also resize images but css should display it much smaller anyway so I guess thats not important.

Comment: Weird. The script cannot find 10s.jpg and not find 75s.jpg if both files are present in directory.

Comment: You can check what the page source looks like between the two. does it really translate to "<img src="../product_pics/75s.jpg">?

Comment: yes it does. I checked page source where image should be displayed, and exact same code appear. When I follow image link in source mode, it will show source of 404 page.

Comment: @Bertrand script and browser can find 10s.jpg but cannot find 75s.jpg. Thats super weird I can tell

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file? If so, add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies.

This is what happened.

I moved my project to subdirectory and didn't fix links to images.
Images from 1s.jpg to 10s.jpg only worked, because they were coincidentally placed also in root folder. New images however, has been added only inside subfolder where path wasn't correct.

Thank you and Sorry again I nearly checked if gravity is still working.

Comment: Simpliest is often true :)